# How I make the arrows to be same, but represent a trend in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need my map to look like this: [image: Reference]

But now it only shows shows the colour of an arrow and the legend is comletely wrong

Dataframe:

```
instorks_trends <- data.frame(
  Country = c("Portugal", "Spain", "Belgium", "Denmark", "Germany", "France", "Netherlands", "Sweden", "Switzerland","Liechtenstein", "Luxembourg","Finland", "Estonia", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Austria", "Poland", "Russia", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Czech Republic", "Ukraine", "Hungary", "Belarus", "Albania", "Bulgaria", "Greece", "Croatia", "Italy", "Macedonia", "Moldova", "Romania", "Serbia", "Montenegro", "Kosovo", "Turkey", "Algeria", "Morocco", "Libya", "Tunisia", "Armenia", "Azerbaijan", "Georgia", "Iran","Iraq", "Israel", "Syria", "Uzbekistan","Tajikistan","Kazakhstan","Kyrgyzstan","Turkmenistan", "South Africa"),
  '2014' = c(11691, 46000, 105, 2, 6152, 2579, 950, 44, 376, 6, 2, 1, 5000, 13900, 19500, 391, 52735, 9000, 1231, 266, 792, 40000, 4950, 22300, 4, 5671, 2357, 1756, 262, 817, 190, 4374, 1248, 1, 40, 8693, NA, 2931, 1400,NA, 644, 278, 104, NA, 70, NA, 4, 1200, 8, 24, 20, 0, NA),
  '2004' = c(7685, 33217, 50, 3, 4482, 941, 523, 29, 198, 0, 0, 0, 4500, 10600, 13000, 395, 52500, 10200, 1331, 240, 814, 30000, 5300, 21362, 3, 4826, 2157, 1700, 70, NA, NA, 5000, NA, NA, NA, 6195, 6601, 1802, 25, 572, 548, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 745, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6)
)
```

Joined map:

```
world_map <- getMap(resolution = "coarse")
joined_map <- joinCountryData2Map(instorks_trends, joinCode = "NAME", nameJoinColumn = "Country")

european_countries <- c("Portugal", "Spain", "Belgium", "Denmark", "Germany", "France", "Netherlands", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Liechtenstein", "Luxembourg", "Finland", "Estonia", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Austria", "Poland", "Russia", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Czech Republic", "Ukraine", "Hungary", "Belarus", "Albania", "Bulgaria", "Greece", "Croatia", "Italy", "Macedonia", "Moldova", "Romania", "Serbia", "Montenegro", "Kosovo", "Turkey")
```

```
instorks_trends <- instorks_trends %>%
  mutate(Trend = X2014 - X2004)

mymap <- fortify(joined_map)
mymap <- mymap |> left_join(instorks_trends, by = c("id" = "Country"))

mymap$monarch <- mymap$id %in% instorks_trends$Country
mymap$monarch <- mymap$id %in% european_countries

# This code is to prepare the labels of each country
country_coord <- data.frame(coordinates(joined_map),stringsAsFactors=F)
country_coord <- country_coord[european_countries,]
country_coord <- country_coord |> tibble::rownames_to_column("id") 
country_coord <- country_coord |>   
  left_join(mymap |> select(id, Trend) |> distinct(id, .keep_all = T),
            by = "id")

arrows_data <- subset(mymap, !is.na(Trend)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(long = mean(long),
            lat = mean(lat),
            Trend = mean(Trend))

# Plot the map with arrows
ggplot(data = mymap, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
  theme_void() +
  geom_map(map = mymap,
           aes(group = group, map_id = id,
               fill = monarch),
           color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#666666", "#ffffff")) +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-10, 50), ylim = c(35, 75)) +
  theme(legend.position = "right") + 
  geom_segment(data = arrows_data,
               aes(x = long, y = lat, xend = long + 0.1, yend = lat + 0.1),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")),
               color = ifelse(arrows_data$Trend >= 0, "green", "red"),
               size = 1.5)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh765.png)
I have also tried to add polygon, but it made it worse

```
geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill = Trend), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "green", midpoint = 0, na.value = "gray")
```

The choropleth map wuld not suit me, since I need an exact replication of the map in the pictire.

Comment: We don't have `instorks_trends` or `joined_map`, so we can't run your code or provide you with a demonstrable working example. That's why a good question should include a [mre]

Comment: In addition to the above comment, unless you _absolutely have to_ reproduce that example map (e.g. for homework/coursework), the use of symbols in this manner is not the most effective way to communicate the trends in your data. Instead, you could consider producing a choropleth map.