# How to create a map in R Markdown file

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I need to create R markdown file in which I need to create country maps like fig. 2 and fig.3  (https://bergenhusen.nabu.de/weissstorch/17202.html) how do I do this? Need to create map showing countries on it as well need to highlight countries to reflect the datapoints.

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Get map data for Europe
europe_map <- map_data("world") %>% 
  filter(region %in% c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark",
                        "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Ireland", "Italy", 
                        "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Portugal", 
                        "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "United Kingdom"))

# Plot the map
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = europe_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16, face = "bold", color = "blue"),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20, "pt"))
```

Comment: Hi samir chavda, welcome to SO. Given that fig 3. in that link you have provided is identical to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77876186/2530121), I'm guessing you are both doing the same course? As with that linked question, you have not provided enough information required of an SO question. Please review [How to write a good R question with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) and update your question to include some example data. You can do this using the `dput()` function. Thanks

Comment: One other comment:  there is no region named `"United Kingdom"` in that dataset.  It uses the abbreviation `"UK"`.